# Coldfusion query isnt working correctly

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

So this is the code

```
SELECT *
FROM users

INSERT INTO users 
(id, username, real_name, password, mail, motto, ip_register, ip_current, machine_id)
VALUES 
(
   #koekwous#, 
   <CFQUERYPARAM VALUE="#form.username#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" MAXLENGTH="50">, 
   jibbo, 
   <CFQUERYPARAM VALUE="#hash(form.password, "SHA-512")#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" MAXLENGTH="128">,
   <CFQUERYPARAM VALUE="#form.email#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" MAXLENGTH="50">,
   welkom,
   ::1,
   ::1,
   ::1
);
```

It should work, but whenever it runs I'm getting this error:

> **Executing Database Query.**
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near `::1, ::1, ::1)` at line 2

Comment: Add your table structure and columns data types, also what is the error?

Comment: Take away the select query.  Your last three values look suspect as well.

Comment: For starters, what are those ::1  things supposed to be?   That's not going to fly.

Comment: Those last 3 values should probably be quoted, assuming the corresponding columns hold text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some quotes to the IP values and machine ID, something like:

( ..., welkom, '::1', '::1', '::1' );